# IIS cache with PURGE support

Tags: windows, iis, caching, reverse-proxy

On Unix, I normally deploy nginx in front of Varnish in front of my application server. Both nginx and Varnish are acting as reverse proxies here. Varnish maintains a cache and supports things like If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control response headers and PURGE requests from the application. nginx is good at receiving a lot of connections. I also use it to serve some static content, enable gzip compression etc.

On Windows, I can manage with Squid in front of IIS. I'm planning to deploy my (Python) application as an ISAPI wildcard filter (using the isapi-wsgi package), so the application will live in a thread pool managed by IIS.

However, Squid development on Windows appears to have stalled, and I'd prefer to keep IIS on port 80, so that I can serve certain things directly from disk. I also suspect IIS is more resilient in handling lots of connections than Squid on Windows.

What do people normally use here? One option would be to use another free-standing caching proxy in front of IIS. Another option may be something installed as an ISAPI filter, which would intercept requests and respond to things like If-Modified-Since, requets for images and other cached resources, and PURGE requests from the application.

Does such a thing exist? Or are the only real choices Squid and MS ISA (too expensive).

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 with Application Request Routing (see http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) supports full proxy caching on the same box or with the cache server in front of your middle tier.

Once ARR is installed, to enable proxy caching from the command line run the following:

```
%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/diskCache /+"[path='C:\MyCacheFolder',maxUsage='0']" /commit:apphost
```

To vary caching based on query string, execute the following:

```
%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/proxy /cache.queryStringHandling:"Accept"  /commit:apphost
```

See the documentation link above for more details.  Notice that static and dynamic content can have different caching strategies, etc.  If you pursue using this, follow up with specific questions--it can be a bit of a trick lining everything up if you're looking for fine-grained control.